# How can I push the item to the promise<array[]>?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Promise< NewArticle[]>'.

```
    return await relatedArticles.reduce(
      async (newArticleList: Promise<NewArticle[]>, relatedArticle: FormattedRelatedArticle) => {
        const article = await this.getArticle()
        if (article) {
          newArticleList.push({...article, relatedArticle.url})
        }
        return newArticleList
      },
      Promise.resolve([])
    )
```

btw, is this a good practice to write reduce async like this?

Comment: Why is the `prevArticle` a `Promise` at all?

Comment: @Christian — Because the reducer function is `async` so always returns a promise.

Comment: Why is the `relatedArticle` argument not used in the reducer function?

Comment: What about the `this.getArticle()` call? It will return the same article in every pass in the loop no?

Comment: the `relatedArticle` will merge with the `await this.getArticle()`. and then push to prevArticle

Comment: `{...article, relatedArticle.url}` shouldn't compile. You need a key for the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's wise to use `reduce` here. It degrades readability and can easily be solved with another type of loop like this:

```
const newArticleList: NewArticle[];
for (const relatedArticle of relatedArticles) {
    const article = await this.getArticle()
    if (article) {
      newArticleList.push({...article, url: relatedArticle.url});
    }
}
return newArticleList;
```

If `this.getArticle()` always returns the same article then it can be solved with:

```
const article = await this.getArticle();
const newArticleList: NewArticle[] = !article ? [] : relatedArticles.map((relatedArticle: FormattedRelatedArticle) => ({...article, url: relatedArticle.url}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do sth like this?:

```js
        const [newArticleResults, article] = await Promise.all([
          newArticleList,
          this.getArticle()
        ]);
        if (article) {
          newArticleResults.push({...article, relatedArticle.url})
        }
        return newArticleResults
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your prevArticle is inmutable, try to make a copy.

```
let prevArticleMutable = { ...prevArticle };
prevArticleMutable .push(article)
return prevArticleMutable
```

and then push your article, or you can chande reduce prototype and use map, y apply same filter like this:

```
var targetAticles = relatedArticles.map( async (x) => {

   const article = await this.getArticle()
   if (article) {
      return  article
   }

});
```

Comment: `prevArticle` is a promise. It isn't immutable. It just isn't an array or array-like object.

Comment: I want come up a new array with a new interface with more attr on it. map doesn't work

Comment: `map`'s callback should return something if `article` is falsy.

Comment: I just one example, but @Quentin has right,  It just isn't an array.